# How to disable HERE map dragging and zooming in android

Tags: android, here-api

I want to disable HERE map drag and zoom in android.

```
@Override
public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {..)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable using `MapFragment` object after `onEngineInitializationCompleted` called.

For dragging and zooming :

```
mapFragment.getMapGesture().setPinchEnabled(false);
mapFragment.getMapGesture().setPanningEnabled(false);
mapFragment.getMapGesture().setKineticFlickEnabled(false);
```

You can disable other events like single tap,double tap etc as above.

Comment: but what about  onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {..}

Comment: yes your answer is solved my problem @Akash Patel                                         i need reputation for vote  your answers  please vote my question ....